# Chart.js V2.7.2 How to make Horizontal scroll bar without loosing Y-Axis

Tags: scroll, chart.js

I see some solutions but they are not working in V 2.7.2
Is there any way without using animation - make static Y-axis and scroll horizontal

Comment: I am using Chart v2.7.2 and want to have horizontal scrolling . Is there any solution in this version ?I have tick points of about 20 to 30 dynamically generating based on data. I want to display only 10  labels on X-axis and remaining shows only on scrolling. Any solution for this?

Comment: I am not able to control the Ticks. When i say maxTicksLimit :5 . Is it supposed to show only 5 tick points ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I haven't yet found a way to achieve this without using animation. However, I have managed to find a solution that works in Chart.js 2.7.2.

https://jsfiddle.net/EmmaLouise/eb1aqpx8/3/

This approach handles different DPR settings and will scale the axis to match the scaling that Chart.js applies to its charts. It also calls .clearRect() on the original Y axis that Chart.js draws, clearing the pixels in the defined area which means that there is no duplication of axes or overlaps.

**CSS:**

```
.chartWrapper {
 position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
        <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
          <canvas id="chart-Test" height="300" width="1200"></canvas>
        </div>
     </div>
     <canvas id="axis-Test" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(function () {
    var rectangleSet = false;

    var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
    var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                titleFontSize: 0,
                titleMarginBottom: 0,
                bodyFontSize: 12
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: function () {
                    if (!rectangleSet) {
                        var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                       

                        var sourceCanvas = chartTest.chart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-Test").getContext("2d");

                        targetCtx.scale(scale, scale);
                        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth * scale;
                        targetCtx.canvas.height = copyHeight * scale;

                        targetCtx.canvas.style.width = `${copyWidth}px`;
                        targetCtx.canvas.style.height = `${copyHeight}px`;
                        targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);

                        var sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d');

                        // Normalize coordinate system to use css pixels.

                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);
                        rectangleSet = true;
                    }
                },
                onProgress: function () {
                    if (rectangleSet === true) {
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var sourceCtx = chartTest.chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't show any horizontal scroll bar, no way to scroll

Answer (score 0):

simple way to achieve this is

make the inner div width dynamically.
so [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RegNA.png)based on the number of bars the width gets changed